# I downloaded ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386 but can't install

Tags: installation, 32-bit

I downloaded `ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386.iso` on a Windows 7 laptop with no disc-burner.
When I double-click the file `wubi.exe` I get this message:

```
"C:\ubuntu\wubi.exe is not a valid Win32 application.Q
```

Why this is happening?

How can I install Ubuntu on this computer?

Comment: Does it have a USB port? You can use a flash drive instead of a CD.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following method. This will solve your issue.
I tested this method on my laptop. Currently, I'm answering this question by using Ubuntu 13.10 (32bit) installation inside my Windows 8.1.

## OFFLINE INSTALLATION:

1. DISABLE INTERNET
2. MOUNT 32BIT ISO IN WINDOWS VIRTUAL DRIVE (no additional software is required in the case of windows 8)
3. COPY THE wubi.exe TO SOME OTHER DRIVE; FOR EXMAPLE E:\WUBI-INSTALLER
4. OPEN COMMAND PROMPT (ADMIN)
5. CHANGE DIRECTORY TO E:\WUBI-INSTALLER (i.e. the location in your PC where the installer is copied)
6. USE THE FOLLOWING COMMAND TO TARGET TO 32BIT MOUNTED IMAGE:

   ```
      wubi.exe --force-wubi --32bit
   ```

(with this step, the installer will automatically detect and use the mounted ISO image)

7.COMPLETE THE INSTALLATION

IMPORTANT NOTES:- USE THE wubi.exe FROM THE SAME ISO PACKAGE WHICH YOU'RE USING FOR THE INSTALLATION. Using this method, you can install the 32 bit version of ubuntu inside windows using the downloaded ISO image.

Please, feel free asking any clarification further.

Have a nice day

Sunny

Comment: Please edit your post to create normal text - we need neither UPPER CASE nor **bold**.